# Why Can't I Use istream_iterators in a vector Ctor?

Tags: c++, vector, range, stringstream, istream-iterator

I want to do this:

```
std::istringstream foo( "13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20" );
std::vector<int> bar( std::istream_iterator<int>( bytes ), std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

But rather than recognizing it as the vector range ctor, the compiler thinks that I'm prototyping a function.

Is there a way that I can hint to the compiler what's going on?

Comment: You should post some real code.

Comment: The construction of 'foo' is plain wrong

Comment: Fixed `foo` construction

Comment: Not quite, `std::vector` is not a type.

Comment: Now: Make it 'std::vector<int> bar' and be happy

Comment: rejoice `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11 and uniform initialization you may do

```
std::vector<int> bar{ std::istream_iterator<int>( bytes ), std::istream_iterator<int>() };
```

If not, then change to

```
std::vector bar = std::vector<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>( bytes ), std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

Read more about variable initialization vs function declaration ambiguity on [Sutter's Mill](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/).